# Why my function for reversing a string prints out each element from a new line in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter-notebook

I'm pretty new to python and curious why my function prints out each character from a new line. Any suggestions on how to correct it? Any other implementations of that would be helpful as well.

This how my function looks like

```py
def reverse(word):
    len_word = len(word)
    x = 0
    while x < len_word:
        x += 1
        index = len_word - x 
        print(word[index])
reverse("123abcd")
```

What I get is the input with each character on a new line.

What I want to get: dcba321

Comment: The marked duplicate answers the question you asked. But please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python for more direct ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`print()` adds a newline by default. A [general way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493399/7431860) to deal with this is:

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.write(word[index])
```

If you're using python3, you can also do:

```py
print(word[index], end='')
```